# MVC Nhibernate - Acces to path ???.hbm.xml denied

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Vista, VS2008, MVC 1.0.

I have a MVC app using FluentNHibernate to do the configruation.

I have published the app to IIS7 on local machine.

When I browse the app I get error

'C:\Users\Malcolm\Documents\Temp\MyProject.Domain.Ingredient.hbm.xml' is denied

First thing is I am using FluentNhibernate so why is it using xml files for configuration??

Second the error says add ASPNET permissions for the folder but why is it suing Temp folder??

Thridly I can't add ASPNET permissions because when I try to add Vista says no ASPNET account exists???

Malcolm

Answer (score 1):

Fluent NHibernate generates temporary .hbm.xml files that are used to construct the ISessionFactory. I guess you need to grant write permissions on the Temp folder to the ASPNET account on your server.

Answer (score 0):

As @darin said, you were on the right track with the permissions, but in Vista the account used to run ASP.Net apps was changed.  It's no longer ASPNET, it's now called "NETWORK SERVICE" (yes, there is a space in the name)